# a ClassNotFoundException error when trying to excute a Cordova push notification plugin

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

i get a `ClassNotFoundException` error when i was trying to execute this [example](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova) of a push notification plugin:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.cordova2.gcm/com.cordova2.gcm.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cordova2.gcm.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.cordova2.gcm-1.apk`

this is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cordova2.gcm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.cordova2.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.cordova2.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.cordova2.gcm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.cordova2.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

      <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Usually this means that the manifest file is wrong in some way, but I've double checked everything I can think of.

Here is my activity class:

```
package com.cordova2.gcm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here][1] is the answer which worked for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599459/phonegap-class-not-found-error-in-android?

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599459/phonegap-class-not-found-error-in-android?

Answer (score 0):

Did you registered your plugin inside config.xml ?

```
<plugins>
<plugin name="PushPlugin" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" /> 
</plugins>
```

Comment: u can able to click com.plugin.gcm.pushplugin and its redirect to ur java src package ??